# Python itertools.groupby length key?

Tags: python

using python 3.6

Is there a way to return the length of a `groupby` generator as its key?

so this:

```
from itertools import groupby

x = [1,1,1,1,1,
     2,2,2,2,
     3,3,3,
     4,4,
     5]

for key, group in groupby(x): # Some lambda function here?
    print(key,'|', group)
```

would output:

```
5 | <itertools._grouper object at 0x0000016D0FFD45C0>
4 | <itertools._grouper object at 0x0000016D0FFD4668>
3 | <itertools._grouper object at 0x0000016D0FFD4400>
2 | <itertools._grouper object at 0x0000016D0FFD45C0>
1 | <itertools._grouper object at 0x0000016D0FFD4668>
```

Cheers.

Comment: You could get the length from individual groups: `sum(1 for _ in group)`.

Comment: Then the group data is lost and you only have the key?

Comment: In your case it's just `[key] * length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that isn't possible. But you could always convert the group to a list and print its length:

```
for key, group in groupby(x): 
    sub_list = list(group)
    print(len(sub_list),'|', sub_list)
```

Output:

```
5 | [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
4 | [2, 2, 2, 2]
3 | [3, 3, 3]
2 | [4, 4]
1 | [5]
```

Comment: Yep, thanks. I was hoping to avoid the cost of iterating through generators that I wouldn't need the data from. Due to the `len being < 4` in my case.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind loading the generators into lists, you could do that and check their length

```
for key, group in groupby(x):
    l = list(group)
    print(len(l))
    do_something_else_with_list(l)
```

If you meant that you want to check how long the `groupby` itself is, the you can do the same with that:

```
groupby_list = list(groupby(x))
print(len(groupby_list))
```

Just be careful, once you turned a generator into a list the generator itself cannot be iterated over again, and you should only use the list (or re-create the generator)

Comment: I didn't think u'd be able to pull out the length of the group match. Your solution is simple, I like it. I only want to iterate through groups of `len > 4`. but its a small cost to iterate through such a small list.